# Как добавить текст для каждой точки на линейном графике nvd3?

Tags: javascript, html, диаграммы, d3.js

У меня есть линейный график и есть необходимость добавить на каждую точку в этом графике определенный текст. Не совсем понимаю как это можно сделать. Буду очень признателен за помощь )

```js
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
    .margin({
      left: 100
    })
    .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
    .showLegend(true)
    .showYAxis(true)
    .showXAxis(true);

  chart.xAxis
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',r'));

  chart.yAxis
    .tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));

  var myData = getData();

  d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(myData)
    .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(function() {
    chart.update()
  });
  return chart;
});

function getData() {
  return [{
    key: 'Data',
    values: [{
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      },
      {
        x: 1,
        y: 5
      },
      {
        x: 2,
        y: 1
      },
      {
        x: 3,
        y: 4
      },
      {
        x: 4,
        y: 3
      }
    ]
  }];
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/novus/nvd3/v1.8.1/build/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/novus/nvd3/v1.8.1/build/nv.d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="chart" style="width: 500; height: 300;">
    <svg></svg>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Пример итогового графика:
[image: Пример графика]

Comment: Текст должен быть возле точки и всегда видным? или тот попап текст который показывается если мышкой наводишь на точку?

Comment: должен быть всегда видным и находиться возле точки